# FLTK - FL_Tooltip - Modify tooltip size

Tags: c++, oop, tooltip, declaration, fltk

I am using FLTK 1.3.5 (on Mac, Catalina 10.15.5, clang version 11.0.3) and I would like to have widgets with [tooltips](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Tooltip.html) for whom I want to decide margins and other options. In particular, I want to work on `margin_width` and on `wrap_width`, so I tried the following

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Tooltip.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Fl_Window *G_win = 0;
    G_win = new Fl_Window(300,300,"Test");

    Fl_Box* B;
    B = new Fl_Box(10,10,280,280,"Test Tooltip");
    Fl_Tooltip::margin_width(12);
    B->tooltip("I want a huge tooltip!");


    G_win->end();
    G_win->show(argc, argv);
    
    return Fl::run();
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
    Fl_Tooltip::margin_width(12);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~
/usr/local/include/FL/Fl_Tooltip.H:95:3: note: 'margin_width' declared here
  static int margin_width() { return 3; }
```

After carefully looking to [Fl_Tooltip.H](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/Fl__Tooltip_8H_source.html), it seems that the function I want to use is enabled if the `FLTK_ABI_VERSION` variable is greater or equal to 10301 (line 81 of the header file). I inspected the file [Enumerations.H](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/Enumerations_8H_source.html) and I checked that even if I have FLTK 1.3.5 `FLTK_ABI_VERSION` is 10300.
Indeed, `FLTK_ABI_VERSION` is defined as `FL_MAJOR_VERSION*10000 + FL_MINOR_VERSION*100` thus it will be always lower than 10301, being `FL_MAJOR_VERSION` equal to 1 `FL_MINOR_VERSION` equal to 3 in my case.

Moreover, the same header file says that actually `FLTK_ABI_VERSION` is deprecated and it will be substituted by `FL_API_VERSION`, which is exactly 10305 and corresponds to FLTK 1.3.5.

Is this a bug in the original code or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you building on Linux or Windows.  The comparison works on Linux but not on Windows

Comment: @cup I am working on Mac: I forgot to directly mention it in the question.

Comment: It is probably a problem that exists on Mac and Windows but not on gcc.  You probably need to raise it with https://www.fltk.org/applications/str.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Mac but to get this to work on MS compilers

```
#if FLTK_ABI_VERSION >= 10301
```

should be changed to

```
#if (FLTK_ABI_VERSION >= 10301)
```

Try that on the Mac.  If it works, please report the bug and fix to https://www.fltk.org/applications/str.php and remember to specify Mac and Windows.

I've looked through the regression tests - I can't find a test for it.  I suspect the feature was only tested on Linux

**Edit**

You will also need to modify FL_Tooltip.cxx and rebuild the FLTK library

**Edit**

For reference, have a look at README.abi-version.txt.  After adding the brackets, reconfigure with

```
./configure --with-abiversion=10305
```

Then make install

Comment: I tried but it does not work, I get the same above error. I tried also to write `#if FLTK_ABI_VERSION >=0`, but it seems to do not work either, I get errors like `use of undeclared identifier       'margin_width_'; did you mean 'margin_width'?
  static int margin_width() { return margin_width_; }`. I will report the bug, I wanted to check if someone here in SO knew the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried with the brackets as you suggested and I get the same error reported in the question. I tried then to modify the `if` statement with `0` (with and without the brackets) and I get errors about the variables' names: it seems that the names with the final underscore like `margin_width_` are not declared.

Comment: They are declared in FL_tooltip.cxx - it also has the if statement which needs to be modified.  Then you  need to rebuild the library

Comment: I'll download again the library and do the modification as you suggested!

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested but it did not work: I will try to report this bug on the website of FLTK, even it is written that they are concentrating on developing the 1.4 version...

Comment: So you added the brackets to the header in 2 places, the cxx file in one place, rebuilt and it still doesn't work?   Try changing FLTK_ABI_VERSION to FL_API_VERSION.

Comment: Yep, I tried also to change FLTK_ABI_VERSION to FL_API_VERSION but it did not work. I tried another way. Before the `make` command, I run `./configure --with-abiversion=10305`, then I did `make` and `make install`: now everything is working! This suggestion was in the file `README.abi-version.txt` . If you may add this part to your answer, I will sign it as accepted.